# how to convert audio output data into frames using AVFoundation in iphone sdk

Tags: audio, video, avfoundation, video-capture, audio-capture

I am trying to capture the video and audio using `AVCaptureSession` and I done with videocapturing and converted into pixel buffer and I played the output captured video at server side using `ffmpeg n rtmp server`. But the thing is how can I make the  audio to be converted info data and play it at sever side where the data received. And want to know what the audio format is the audio that is captured.

Thank's All,
MONISH

Comment: please share your code how you send video frame and audio simultaneously to server.